# How can i convert a QByteArray into a hex string?

Tags: qt, qt5

I have the blow QByteArray.

```
QByteArray ba;
ba[0] = 0x01;
ba[1] = 0x10;
ba[2] = 0x00;
ba[3] = 0x07;
```

I have really no idea how to convert this QByteArray into resulted string which have "**01100007**", which i would use the QRegExp for pattern matching on this string?

Comment: you should win username of the week. Seriously. Aside from that, please accept hyde's old answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, the `QByteArray` does not contain "hex values", it contains bytes (as it's name implies). Number can be "hex" only when it is printed as text.

Your code should be:

```
QByteArray ba(4, 0); // array length 4, filled with 0
ba[0] = 0x01;
ba[1] = 0x10;
ba[2] = 0x00;
ba[3] = 0x07;
```

Anyway, to convert a `QByteArray` to a hex string, you got lucky: just use [`QByteArray::toHex()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toHex) method!

```
QByteArray ba_as_hex_string = ba.toHex();
```

Note that it returns 8-bit text, but you can just assign it to a `QString` without worrying much about encodings, since it is pure ASCII. If you want upper case *A-F* in your hexadecimal numbers instead of the default *a-f*, you can use [`QByteArray::toUpper()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toUpper) to convert the case.

Comment: Is that `QByteArray ba_as_hex_string` is meant to be `QString ba_as_hex_string` ?

Comment: @Kingsley No, toHex returns an 8-bit US ASCII string. The last paragraph discusses converting to QString.

Answer (score -1):

QString has following contructor:

constructor QString(const QByteArray &ba)

But note that an octal number is preceeded by 0 in c++, so some of your values are deciamal, some octal, none of them are hex.